# C# ASP.NET navbar image path changes in different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

I'm doing an C# ASP.NET web application, just in my learning stage.

I have a navbar in my **Site.Master** and when I am in my **Default.aspx** (`/~`), the image can be seen. 
But when I change page eg. to (`~/Account/Register`) the image can not be found.

The code to Image in my navbar:

```
<a href="~/" class="navbar-left"><img style="margin:10px; margin-left:30px;" width="30px" height="30px" src="logo_abstract.png"></a>
```

To see the whole code for my `Site.Master` and `MainContent` , here it is the relevant code, containing the above code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="~/" class="navbar-left"><img style="margin:10px; margin-left:30px;" width="30px" height="30px" src="brain_stransparent_abstract.png"></a>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">TestApp</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contat</a></li>
            </ul>
            <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/18x18" class="profile-image img-circle"> 
                                <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> <b class="caret"></b>

                            </a>
                            </a></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Test</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

I think, I need to set a path to my image, that is the same path from everywhere, but I don't know any word for this, to google or something.

Comment: If you look closely at the code you posted, you'll see a tilde mark `~` which means "application root" path. Use it to reference paths for your resources (images, css, js) to construct the necessary paths "from the root of your application" (not file system). e.g. `~/images/foo.png`. Hth

Answer (score 0):

This is because at runtime the path in internal pages can't locate the images so for any link or image paths you should use Page.ResolveUrl method

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Account/Manage.aspx"); %>" class="navbar-left"><img style="margin:10px; margin-left:30px;" width="30px" height="30px" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/logo_abstract.png"); %>"></a>
```

Hope it helps